# TYPO3 felogin with Bootstrap Alerts

Tags: typo3, felogin

i use the TYPO3 extension felogin. I can configure different texts here. But I would like to show a bootstrap alert if someone entered wrong user data. How can I do something like this? On the page https://t3bootstrap.de//en/extensions/felogin/ there is an example, but I do not know how this is implemented. Does somebody has any idea?

Best regards
MS-Tech

Answer (score 0):

I'd first open the `Template` Module in the TYPO3 backend and select `TypoScript-Object-Browser` from the select. Then switch to `Setup` view in the next select box.
You'll see all TypoScript nodes here.
Find the node `plugin.tx_felogin_pi1.templateFile` to figure out the path to the template file which is used for the login.
Now simply edit that file and replate the error message markups with bootstrap alerts.

(Always good to know which TYPO3 version you are on to provide better answers.)

**edit:**
*the fe_login markers can be wrapped in TypoScript:*

```
plugin.tx_felogin_pi1 {
    successMessage_stdWrap.wrap = <div class="alert alert-success">|</div>
    errorMessage_stdWrap.wrap = <div class="alert alert-danger">|</div>
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. I have already found the template and have already edited something. I do not know how to include the bootstrap alerts in the template. I have e.g. only one marker ### STATUS-MESSAGE ### for general messages and also the error messages. Do you have an example for me? Thanks in advance...

Comment: you could wrap this markers with the bootstrap markup for alerts. try to use this TypoScript setup:
`plugin.tx_felogin_pi1.successMessage_stdWrap.wrap = <div class="alert alert-success">|</div>`


`plugin.tx_felogin_pi1.errorMessage_stdWrap.wrap = <div class="alert alert-danger">|</div>`